# How to remove firebase database listener when ref path is no longer available

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase in a react native app and I have a listener similar to this:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+uid+'/items').on('value', function(snapshot){
    ....
})
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove that listener when the user logs out. I know that I can do it using `off()` like:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+uid+'/items').off('value', function(snapshot){
    ....
})
```

But once the user logs out I no longer have access to the user id. So how do I remove the listener?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to retain the path on which you've attached the listener so that you can call `off()` on it. One way to do this would be:

```
mUserRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+uid+'/items');
mUserRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    ....
})
```

And then later:

```
mUserRef.off('value');
```

Comment: Does the original ref object need to be used to turn of the listener, or can a new ref with the same path be used to call `.off()`?

Comment: how would you retain/persist the path?...using state?