# How to stop Firebase Listener when i pass to another screen?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Listener with `on` method in Redux action for getting data in a Screen. Here is my redux action code below:

```
export const getSelectedProjectDetail = (groupUid, projectUid) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_SELECTED_PROJECT_DETAIL_START,
  });

  firebase.database().ref('/groups/' + groupUid + '/projects/' + projectUid).on('value', (mainSnap) => {
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/users/' + mainSnap.val().creator.uid)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      const messagesList = _.map(mainSnap.val().messages, (val, uid) => ({ ...val, uid }));

      for (let index = 0; index < messagesList.length; index++) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + messagesList[index].author.uid).on('value', function (childSnapshot) {
          messagesList[index] = {
            ...messagesList[index],
            author: {
              ...messagesList[index].author,
              name: childSnapshot.val().displayName,
              email: childSnapshot.val().email,
            },
          };
          if (index === messagesList.length - 1) {
            const selectedProjectDetail = {
              ...mainSnap.val(),
              creator: { ...mainSnap.val().creator, name: snapshot.val().displayName },
              messages: _.reverse(messagesList),
            };
            dispatch({
              type: GET_SELECTED_PROJECT_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
              payload: selectedProjectDetail,
            });
            NavigationService.navigate('ProjectDetail');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Problem is that when there are changes in my database while i am on another screen, screen passes to the one with listener. I think, i need to stop listeners when i close the screen. How can i stop them with Firebase functions or any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove firebase database listener when ref path is no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453389/how-to-remove-firebase-database-listener-when-ref-path-is-no-longer-available)

Answer (score 0):

if you add listener in redux be like

```
const myRef = '/users/' + messagesList[index].author.uid



firebase.database().ref(myRef).on('value',
  function (childSnapshot) {
      messagesList[index] = {
          ...messagesList[index],
             author: {
             ...messagesList[index].author,
             name: childSnapshot.val().displayName,
             email: childSnapshot.val().email,
            },
        };
```

And you need to save that `myRef` on redux store

At the time when the component unmounts, in componentWillUnmount
You can dispatch another action and
You can remove the listener by 
`firebase.database().ref('myRef').off('value', callback)`
at that time you can acess `myRef` variable from your redux store

Comment: Is there any way to turn off all listeners with one simple code? Should i remove listeners one by one ?